# malloc handling - identifier not found issue

Tags: c

I'm using visual studio to write a c code.

This is the malloc code line i was told to use:

```
root = (Coor)malloc(sizeof(Coor));
```

It doesn't let me use it for the following error:

```
identifier not found
```

Can anyone tell me why it happens and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Care to finish that error message with the ***identifier*** name claimed to not be found??

Comment: Stupid me… I didn't see the library wan't included. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your code looks broken anyway. Allocating `sizeof(Coor)` bytes and then converting the result to `Coor` makes no sense whatsoever. Either convert to `Coor *` or allocate `sizeof <derefernced Coor>` (of `Coor` is a pointer type). Moreover, casting the result of `malloc` in C can only hide erros, but serves no other meaningful purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please check if you have included `<stdlib.h>` and `<malloc.h>`.